# Disable eslint rule for a bunch of lines together

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

in order to turn off linting rule for a specific line we use the following rule:

```
/* eslint-disable-next-line*/ or /* eslint-disable-line*/...
```

What if I want to disable a bunch of lines together. is there something like:

```
 /* eslint-disable-start*/
<Control.radio model=".rate" className="form-control" name="rating" value="5" id="5" /><label htmlFor="5">☆</label> 
<Control.radio model=".rate" className="form-control" name="rating" value="4" id="4" /><label htmlFor="4">☆</label>
<Control.radio model=".rate" className="form-control" name="rating" value="3" id="3" /><label htmlFor="3">☆</label>
<Control.radio model=".rate" className="form-control" name="rating" value="2" id="2" /><label htmlFor="2">☆</label>
<Control.radio model=".rate" className="form-control" name="rating" value="1" id="1" /><label htmlFor="1">☆</label> 
 /* eslint-disable-End*/
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56714318/how-to-disable-multiple-rules-for-eslint-nextline

Comment: You can see this as well https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/rules