# Disable typescript-eslint plugin rule with inline comment

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint, vite, typescript-eslint

I get an eslint warning that comes from the @typescript-eslint plugin.

> 'instance' is declared but its value is never read. ts(6133)

VSCode suggested the following line as a Quick Fix:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
```

However, adding this line makes no difference, see below:

[image]

**Please note:** I want to use an *inline rule* as shown here to disable the warning for *one specific line* only. I do *not* want to disable it for a whole file, *nor* disable it for the whole project.

PS: This is a fresh Vite project with TypeScript and React.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I have found a solution.

**1.) tsconfig**

In `tsconfig.json`, add the following. This will stop the compiler errors from appearing when building the project with `npm run build`.

You will still get the yellow underline warnings for affected code lines in VSCode (if you haven't yet done anything else to address them).

```
 "compilerOptions": {
    /* Linting */
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
  },
```

**2.) eslintrc**

In `.eslintrc.cjs`, add the following. This will ensure that unused variables get marked as warnings. Alternative options would be to mark them as errors or to ignore them completely. Note that I am disabling the JS version, but enabling the TS version.

Again, you will still get the yellow underline warnings for affected code lines in VSCode (if you haven't yet done anything else to address them).

```
rules: {
    "no-unused-vars": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": "warn",
  }
```

**3.) eslint-disable**

In the file where you want to disable a warning, add an inline rule. Note that, if you want to be specific, you have to add the TS version of the rule, e.g.

```
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
const [instance, setInstance] = useState<SwiperClass | null>(null);
```

Alternatively, you can simply use `// eslint-disable-next-line` without specifying the rule.

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest is to add to your eslintrc file a following rule

```
rules: {
    ...,
    '@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars': [
      'error',
      { argsIgnorePattern: '^_', varsIgnorePattern: '^_' },
    ],
}
```

With this you can get the rid of the error this way :

```
const [_instance, setInstance] = useState(null)
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does not answer the question. I am asking why `eslint-disable-next-line` does not work and how it needs to be changed.

Answer (score -1):

You can avoid the error by destructuring the second element from the array without assigning the first element to a variable:

```
const [, setInstance] = useState<SwiperClass | null>(null);
```

---

I'm not sure exactly why you cannot suppress the error, but it's possible that you need to disable more than one rule.  Possibly the built-in [`no-unused-vars` rule](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-unused-vars) applies here?

```
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars, @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
```

[Here's an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56714489/10431574) about the syntax for disabling multiple rules.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried disabling multiple rules as you suggested. It has no effect.